# Istio Sidecar Injection stuck container creation after enable injection on k8s namepsace

Tags: istio, minikube

I'm running into a problem when enable sidecar istio-injection over minikube local cluster, after apply a deployment manifest the pod never start

Steps reproduced...

```
1. kubectl label namespace udemy istio-injection=enabled
2. kubecl apply -f mydeployment.yaml


6s          Normal    Scheduled   pod/kiada   Successfully assigned udemy/kiada to minikube
4s          Normal    Pulled      pod/kiada   Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.10.3" already present on machine
4s          Normal    Created     pod/kiada   Created container istio-init
4s          Normal    Started     pod/kiada   Started container istio-init
2s          Warning   BackOff     pod/kiada   Back-off restarting failed container
```

Stay stuck

Comment: after looking in pods container the same keeps running forever with the message container "kiada" in pod "kiada" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

Comment: Could you try to run <kubectl describe pods your-pod> and see if there is anything abnormal like reason and Last state?

Answer (score 0):

Can I get the exact deployment.yaml ?
Did you attach any volumes/configmaps/secrets in it? if yes, please make sure all those are available before you deploy.

Comment: Thanks for reply, well the deployment is a basic pod creation, that's without istio-injection runs normally, but if I apply istio-injection over namespace, any Pod starts I tried look the events in kubernetes but without success

Comment: Can I get the complete deployment yaml file? you can hide the sensitive information and share

Comment: ```apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kiada
spec:
  containers:
    - name: kiada
      image: luksa/kiada:0.1
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080```

Comment: Answer can be comment